# update fields from cron odoo

Tags: python, api, odoo

I want to update a field by another field model

for example when I select an employee I want to update his coordinates in (hr.employee)

```
class hr_employee(models.Model):
    _name = 'hr.employee.transfer'
    _rec_name = 'employee_id'




    def _cron_transfert(self):
        current_date = datetime.now() 
        transfer = self.env['hr.employee.transfer'].search([('date_transfer' ,'>', current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),('state','=','done')])
        for employee in transfer: 
            employee.address_id = transfer.address_id_new 
            employee.job_id = transfer.job_id_new
            print '-------------------',transfer.job_id_new    


    date_cration = fields.Date(string='Date order', required=True, default=datetime.today())
    date_transfer = fields.Date(string='Date of actual transfer' ,required=True)
    employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee',string='Employee', required=True)
    country_work_id = fields.Many2one('res.country',string='Country', required=True)
    country_id = fields.Many2one('res.country',string='Nationality',  required=True)   
    job_id = fields.Many2one('hr.job',string='Job title',  required=True) 
    state_work_id = fields.Many2one('res.country.state',string='Fed. State', domain="[('country_id', '=', country_work_id)]",  required=True)   
    working_address = fields.Many2one('res.partner',string='Working Address',  required=True)   

    job_id_new = fields.Many2one('hr.job',string='Job title',  required=True) 
    address_id_new = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Working Address new',  required=True)




    state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft', 'Draft'),
        ('accept', 'Director Manager'),
        ('done', 'Done'),
        ('cancel', 'Cancel'),
    ], string='Order Status', readonly=True, copy=False, store=True, default='draft')
```

I want to change the field **address_id** (in 'hr.employee) by this **address_id_new**
and
the field **job_id** (in 'hr.employee) by this **job_id_new**

i add the function _cron_transfert  in Cron (XML) but if when i clic Run Manually 
This error is vanishing
 ( ValueError: Expected singleton: hr.employee.transfer(37, 38)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all
I found the solution and it is

```
def _cron_emp(self):
    current_date = datetime.now() 
    record= self.env['hr.employee.transfer'].search([('date_transfer' ,'<=', current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),('state','=','done')])
    for rec in record: 
        rec.employee_id.job_id= transfer.job_id_new
        rec.employee_id.address_id = transfer.address_id_new
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like this

```
    def _cron_transfert(self):
        current_date = datetime.now() 
        transfer = self.env['hr.employee.transfer'].search([('date_transfer' ,'>', current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),('state','=','done')])
        for employee in transfer: 
            employee.address_id = employee.address_id_new.id 
            employee.job_id = employee.job_id_new.id
            print '-------------------',transfer.job_id_new
```